# How to show banner ads in relative layout programmatically

Tags: android, admob

Why banner ads not showing in relative layout programmatically ?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            tools:context=".HomeActivity">

        </RelativeLayout >
```

**Java**

```
void loadAds() {
        if (checkInternet.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            databaseReference = database.getReference("Test").child("Ads");
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Banner = dataSnapshot.child("Banner").getValue().toString();
                    Interstitial = dataSnapshot.child("Interstitial").getValue().toString();
                    Rewarded = dataSnapshot.child("Rewarded").getValue().toString();
                    InterstitialPage = dataSnapshot.child("InterstitialPage").getValue().toString();
                    AdView mAdView = new AdView(HomeActivity.this);
                    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
                    mAdView.setAdUnitId(Banner);
                    relative_layout.addView(mAdView);
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I hope you help me to find a solution.

Comment: Can you explain `what's working and what's not` with the above code?

Comment: @prashant17 I just want show ads , button , text etc... inside relative layout can you put example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with test ads if it works then the problem is with your ad number

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to put adView inside relative layout in xml like this:

```
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

and change ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 to your adUnitId.
also check [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)

Hope this help you